# Tiny MCE change the format dropdown display text

Tags: javascript, tinymce, rte

Tiny MCE has a format select method: theme_advanced_blockformats dropdown in which you can select formatting. It shows values like: paragraph, heading 1, heading 2 etc. I want to change the names shown in this dropdown. For instance I want to show "heading 1" as "sub heading". It makes more sense to the client working with the editor. Is there a way to do this in the tinyMCE.init? Not in the configuration files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. To set theme_advanced_blockformats use

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        theme_advanced_blockformats : "p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,blockquote,dt,dd,code,samp"
});
```

To change the title you will have to modify the lang files under `tiny_mce/themes/advanced/langs/en.js`

**Update:**

You may change the title using the oninit and setup tinymce configuration parameter in tinymce.init:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.i18n['en.advanced.h1'] = 'My desired title';
```

So, you could try:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
     ed.onBeforeRenderUI.add(function(ed, cm) {
         tinymce.EditorManager.i18n['en.advanced.h1'] = 'My desired title';
     });
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But I was specifically looking for a way to do this without having to change the lang files under tiny_mce/themes/advanced/langs/en.js. So changing it on a -per instance- basis (within the init) not globally.

Comment: Looks great! But at which point should I invoke this? I can get the value but seem not able to set it.

Comment: hmm, this might get a bit tricky. the i18n stuff needs to be set before the tinymce UI gets rendered, see my updated answer

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get, how I can get to the tinyMCE.init without 'hacking', that is, within the bounds of my theme. Starting from say `mytheme/functions.php` (where i.e. I can use the `tiny_mce_before_init` filter and can sucessfully change all kinds of tinyMCE config options), where to place things, to get the above javascript in?

Comment: @Fronker: it depends on your system where the tinymce.init gets called. Joomla for example has a special configuration file which gets red and is used to call that function. There will be a way for your system too.

Comment: @Thariama Yep, still looking for that way... :) there's a filter (callback) to arm the configuration, unsure about direct access to the eventual javascript init call...

Comment: a callback does not seem to be a good way to chagne the configuration because some settings are being processed directly onInit and changing them later has no effect